# How to search in table based on specific column value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement a search box in html table using drop down, so that I can search the data by specific column name heading.

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Fruit</th>
        <th>Color</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Grapes</td>
        <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I got a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tugrulorhan/fd8kb/1/) but this doesn't work in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple script that will add a CSS class for proper column and column values. For example:

```
$("tr:first-child").addClass('fruits');
```

(you can add custom class like '.fruits' for Nth column, not only first-child, its only an example)

then you can write simple custom filter (searching for fruit with 'Z' letter in name) like:

```
var resultsOfSearchingFruitsWithZLetter = [];
$.each($('.fruits'), function(val) {
    if(val.val().indexOf('z') > -1) {
        resultsOfSearchingFruitsWithALetter.push(val.val());
    }
});
```

Comment: I am really new to javascript. So, can you please tell me what all modifications I need to do. It will be really helpful.